# Unable to load @font-face with Chrome, error with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, font-face

Trying to load an @font-face in Chrome, untested with other browsers.

```
@font-face {
font-family: titleFont;
src: url('/fonts/VanadineBold.ttf') format("truetype");
/*Have also tried...*/
/*src: url('/fonts/VanadineBold.woff') format("woff");*/
/*src: url('/fonts/VanadineBold.woff2') format("woff2");*/
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

p#title {
font-family: titleFont, sans-serif;
position: absolute;
top: 5%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Keep's loading the font as sans-serif, as well as throwing this error in console..?

```
jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost:63342/fonts/VanadineBold.ttf 404 (Not Found)
```

This is my folder structure...

The root folder:

[image: Root folder]

Inside the fonts folder:
[image: Inside the fonts folder]

Comment: is your  src location correct? Are you able to include your project structure? in particular show where you have your fonts directory.

Comment: Yes it is correct, 
index.html folder 
https://gyazo.com/94d5499837a8845666dfe4d167642d45

fonts folder
https://gyazo.com/161f63b099a5ada63b1b1991336601a2

Comment: And this loads properly in FireFox ?

Comment: Untested with firefox, only tested with google chrome, so not sure if its a browser issue or what.

Comment: apart from the obvious error of using just one font resource that will not render on all os's, there is the obvious issue of loading the font from localhost. So the question stands @Hooman, are the fonts in the correct place on your development machine?

Comment: If you look at the images Ive sent (gyazo links), thats the path Ive taken to my font file, and the only error that pops up is the jquery error, so unless you can see the issue with the font path, which I believe is correct, Im not sure whats wrong

Comment: i think this path isn't correct : http://localhost:63342/fonts/VanadineBold.ttf. Can be something like this? http://localhost:63342/YOURSITE/fonts/VanadineBold.ttf?

Comment: So the website
localhost:63342/WEBSITENAME/fonts/VanadineBold.ttf
when I entered it into the web browser, it downloaded that font, so the path is correct

Comment: What the error is telling you is that there is no fonts folder in the root directory of your website. And the Project Structure that you have shown, does not confirm if the fonts folder is indeed inside the root of your website or not...

Comment: And what would the root of my website be, considering I entered in the website and it downloaded the font? As my above comment explains

Comment: are you able to show us more of your project structure? I want to know what is the parent folder of your fonts folder... and is you can show us its content.

Comment: The parent folder is the root folder, the folder that is in the image above that has the folder... labeled 'fonts'

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this document](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/), format('truetype') seems to be for Safari.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Try using a .woff font for chrome:

```
src: url('webfont.woff') format('woff')
```

Comment: Converted type to woff2 and still didnt work (also changed the code obviously), and the same error for jquery still pops up.

Comment: Maybe try updating the question with your new code. would be good to improve your project structure photo (showing the fonts inside the font folder)... and show us the root of your project structure (if it is not in the existing image.)

Comment: Just updated the post with more images and code attempts updated too.